# Generación de código y Transformación de plantillas T4 VS 2015: Compilando transformación

Tags: java, html, c#, visual-studio

estoy realizando un proyecto con DSL Tools en Visual Studio 2015. He creado primero un modelo como el de la imagen:
[image: Imagen]

Del cual es importante la relación de "Clase" con "Atributo" y "Metodo", así como "Metodo" con "Parametro"
Al entrar en la sección "Debugging" para generar código HTML y Java, tengo lo siguiente:

**Generación HTML:** Html.tt

```
<#@ template inherits="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.ModelingTextTransformation" language="C#" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".html" #>
<#@ DGD_Junio processor="DGD_JunioDirectiveProcessor" requires="fileName='Test.mydsl4'" #>
<#@ include file="EF.utility.CS.ttinclude" #>

    <#
    if(this.Modelo.Clases.Count>0){
        // definimos una variable para la creación de los ficheros
        var fileManager=EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this); 

        //Para cada clase generamos un fichero
        foreach(Clase e in this.Modelo.Clases){

            //Asociacion N:M fichero adicional
            foreach(Asociacion r in Asociacion.GetLinksToEstaFormado(e)){
                if((r.CardinalidadAs1 == "N" || r.CardinalidadAs1 == "M")&&(r.CardinalidadAs2 == "N" || r.CardinalidadAs2 == "M")){
                    fileManager.StartNewFile(r.Nombre + ".html");   
                    WriteLine("<html>\n<head>\n\t<title>" + r.Nombre + "</title>\n</head>\n<body>");
                    WriteLine("<!--AUTOGENERATED CODE FOR A N:M RELATION-->");

                    //Div
                    WriteLine("<div style='border:1px solid black; margin:20px'>\n");
                    WriteLine("<p style='background-color: gray; color:black;font-weight:bold;font-family: Arial;text-align:center'>"+r.Nombre+"</p><br />");

                    WriteLine("<table><tr>");
                    WriteLine("<td><p style='background-color: lightgray; color:black;font-weight:lighter;font-family: Arial;text-align:center'>"+e.Nombre+"</p><br /></td><td></td>");
                    WriteLine("</tr>");
                    //Tabla de atributos    
                    foreach(Atributo a in e.Atributo){
                        WriteLine("<tr><td style='color:lightblue;font-family:Arial;'>"+ a.Nombre + ":</td><td><input type= 'text'name ='" + a.Nombre + "' style='color:lightblue;font-family: Arial;' /> </td></tr>");
                    }
                    WriteLine("<tr><td><br /><p style='background-color: lightgray; color:black;font-weight:lighter;font-family: Arial;text-align:center'>"+ r.TargetClase.Nombre +"</p><br /></td></tr>");
                    foreach(Atributo a in r.TargetClase.Atributo){
                        WriteLine("<tr><td style='color:lightblue;font-family:Arial;'>"+ a.Nombre + ":</td><td><input type= 'text'name ='" + a.Nombre + "' style='color:lightblue;font-family: Arial;' /> </td></tr>");
                    }
                    WriteLine("</table>\n");        //Fin de la tabla

                    //Form
                    WriteLine("<form name =" + r.Nombre + " style='background-color:white; color:black; font-family : Arial; text-align:center; '>");

                    //Fin
                    WriteLine("\n</form>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>");
                }
            }

            /*
            }else{ //si no es una relacion NM fichero de clase normal
            */
            fileManager.StartNewFile(e.Nombre + ".html");


            WriteLine("<html>\n<head>\n\t<title>" + e.Nombre + "</title>\n</head>\n<body>");
            WriteLine("<!--AUTOGENERATED CODE-->");

            //Div para margenes y bordes
            WriteLine("<div style='border:1px solid black; margin:20px'>");

            if(typeof(ClaseEnriquecida) == e.GetType()){ //Clase enriquecida
                ClaseEnriquecida ce = (ClaseEnriquecida)e;
                WriteLine("<p style='background-color: " + ce.ColorFondo + "; color:" + ce.ColorLetraNombre + ";font-weight:bold;font-family: " + ce.TipoLetraNombre + ";text-align:" + ce.Alineacion + "'>"+e.Nombre+"</p><br />");
                //Formulario
                WriteLine("<form name =" + e.Nombre + " style='background-color:" + ce.ColorFondo + "; color:" + ce.ColorLetraNombre + "; font-family : " + ce.TipoLetraNombre + "; text-align:" + ce.Alineacion + ";'>");
            }else{  //Clase normal
                WriteLine("<p style='background-color: gray; color:black;font-weight:bold;font-family: Arial;text-align:center'>"+e.Nombre+"</p><br />");
                //Formulario
                WriteLine("<form name =" + e.Nombre + " style='background-color:white; color:black; font-family : Arial; text-align:center; '>");
            }

            //Crear tabla atributos
            WriteLine("<table>");

            //Atributos
            if(typeof(ClaseEnriquecida) != e.GetType()){ //Clase normal
                foreach(Atributo a in e.Atributo){
                    WriteLine("<tr><td style='color:lightblue;font-family:Arial;'>"+ a.Nombre + ":</td><td><input type= 'text'name ='" + a.Nombre + "' style='color:lightblue;font-family: Arial;' /> </td></tr>");
                }
            }else{ //Clase enriquecida
                foreach(AtributoEnriquecido a in e.Atributo){
                    if(typeof(AtributoEnriquecido)== a.GetType()){
                        if(a.CheckBox){
                            WriteLine("<tr><td style='color:" + a.ColorLetra + ";font-family:" + a.TipoLetra + ";'>"+ a.Nombre + ":</td><td><input type= 'checkbox' name ='" + a.Nombre + "' style='color:" + a.ColorLetra + ";font-family: " + a.TipoLetra + ";' /> </td></tr>");
                        }else if(a.RadioButton){
                            WriteLine("<tr><td style='color:" + a.ColorLetra + ";font-family:" + a.TipoLetra + ";'>"+ a.Nombre + ":</td><td><input type= 'radio' name ='" + a.Nombre + "' style='color:" + a.ColorLetra + ";font-family: " + a.TipoLetra + ";' /> </td></tr>");
                        }else{
                            WriteLine("<tr><td style='color:" + a.ColorLetra + ";font-family:" + a.TipoLetra + ";'>"+ a.Nombre + ":</td><td><input type= 'text' name ='" + a.Nombre + "' style='color:" + a.ColorLetra + ";font-family: " + a.TipoLetra + ";' /> </td></tr>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            WriteLine("</table>\n");        //Fin de la tabla

            //Metodos
            if(typeof(ClaseEnriquecida) != e.GetType()){ //Clase normal
                foreach(Metodo m in e.Metodo){
                    WriteLine("<input type='submit' name ='" + m.Nombre + "' value='" + m.Nombre + "' style='background-color:lightgray;color:black;font-family:Arial;' />&nbsp;&nbsp");
                }
            }else{  //Clase enriquecida
                foreach(MetodoEnriquecido me in e.Metodo){
                    WriteLine("<input type='submit' name ='" + me.Nombre + "' value='" + me.Nombre + "' style='background-color:lightgray;color:" + me.ColorLetra + ";font-family:" + me.TipoLetra + ";' />&nbsp;&nbsp");
                    }
            }

            //Getters & setters
            if(e.Atributo.Count > 0){
                foreach(Atributo a in e.Atributo){
                    WriteLine("<input type='submit' name ='get" + a.Nombre + "' value='get" + a.Nombre + "' style='background-color:lightgray;color:black;font-family:Arial;' />&nbsp;&nbsp");
                }
                foreach(Atributo a in e.Atributo){
                    WriteLine("<input type='submit' name ='set" + a.Nombre + "' value='set" + a.Nombre + "' style='background-color:lightgray;color:black;font-family:Arial;' />&nbsp;&nbsp");
                }
            }
            /*} //Cierre de clase y relacion*/

            //Cerrar etiquetas
            WriteLine("\n</form>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>");
        }
        fileManager.Process();
    }
    #>
```

**Generación Java:** Java.tt

```
<#@ template inherits="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.ModelingTextTransformation" language="C#" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".java" #>
<#@ DGD_Junio processor="DGD_JunioDirectiveProcessor" requires="fileName='Test.mydsl4'" #>
<#@ include file="EF.utility.CS.ttinclude"#>

<#

if(this.Modelo.Clases.Count>0){

    // definimos una variable para la creación de los ficheros
    var fileManager=EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this); 

    //Para cada clase generamos un fichero
    foreach(Clase e in this.Modelo.Clases){
        fileManager.StartNewFile(e.Nombre + ".java");

        WriteLine("//AUTOGENERATED CODE");

        //Cabecera
        String header = e.Visibilidad;
        if(e.Abstract) header += " abstract";
        header += " class " + e.Nombre;
        if(e.Padre != null) header += " extends " + e.Padre.Nombre;
        header += " {";
        WriteLine(header);

        //Atributos
        if(e.Atributo.Count > 0){
            foreach(Atributo a in e.Atributo){
                WriteLine ("\tprivate " + a.TipoDato + " " + a.Nombre + ";");
            }
        }

        //Clase enriquecida - Atributos
        if(typeof(ClaseEnriquecida) == e.GetType()){
            foreach(Atributo a in e.Atributo){
                if(typeof(AtributoEnriquecido)== a.GetType()){
                    WriteLine("\tprivate " + a.TipoDato + " " + a.Nombre + ";");
                }
            }
        }

        //Constructor
        WriteLine("\n\tpublic " + e.Nombre + "(){\n\n\t}");

        //Getters & Setters
        if(e.Atributo.Count > 0){
            foreach(Atributo a in e.Atributo){
                WriteLine("\n\tpublic void set" + a.Nombre + " (" + a.TipoDato + " " + a.Nombre + "){");
                WriteLine("\t\tthis." + a.Nombre + " = " + a.Nombre + ";\n\t}\n");
            }
            foreach(Atributo a in e.Atributo){
                WriteLine("\n\tpublic " + a.TipoDato + " get" + a.Nombre + "(){");
                WriteLine("\t\treturn this." + a.Nombre + ";\n\t}\n");
            }
        }

        //Metodos
        if(e.Metodo.Count>0){
            foreach(Metodo m in e.Metodo){
                if(typeof(MetodoEnriquecido) != m.GetType()){
                    if(m.Parametro.Count > 0){
                        String parametros = "";
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach(Parametro p in m.Parametro){
                            parametros += p.TipoDato + " " + p.Nombre + ((m.Parametro.Count > 1 && i<m.Parametro.Count -1) ? "," : "");
                            i++;
                        }
                        WriteLine("\tpublic " + m.ValorDeRetorno + " " + m.Nombre + "(" + parametros + "){ \n\t//AUTOGENERATED \n \t}");
                    }else{
                        WriteLine("\tpublic " + m.ValorDeRetorno + " " + m.Nombre + "(){");
                        WriteLine("\t//AUTOGENERATED");
                        WriteLine("\t}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Clase enriquecida - Metodos
        if(typeof(ClaseEnriquecida) == e.GetType()){
            foreach(Metodo m in e.Metodo){
                if(typeof(MetodoEnriquecido) == m.GetType()){
                    if(m.Parametro.Count > 0){
                        String parametros = "";
                        int i =0;
                        foreach(Parametro p in m.Parametro){
                            parametros += p.TipoDato + " " + p.Nombre + ((m.Parametro.Count > 1 && i<m.Parametro.Count -1) ? "," : "");
                            i++;
                        }
                        WriteLine("\tpublic " + m.ValorDeRetorno + " " + m.Nombre + "(" + parametros + "){ \n\t//AUTOGENERATED CLASE ENRIQUECIDA \n \t}");
                    }else{
                        WriteLine("\tpublic " + m.ValorDeRetorno + " " + m.Nombre + "(){");
                        WriteLine("\t//AUTOGENERATED CLASE ENRIQUECIDA");
                        WriteLine("\t}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    //FIN   
    WriteLine("");
    WriteLine("}");
    }
    fileManager.Process();
}

#>
```

Me saltan los siguientes errores al transformar las plantillas T4:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe por qué puede suceder esto? La parte del modelo se compila y funciona perfectamente, pero no consigo generar código. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ese tipo de error me ha pasado antes y bueno en mi caso fue que la referencia .dll generada automáticamente y que contiene las clases referidas en los errores no se está agregando en la carpeta debug. Por eso que al momento de compilar no te va a arrojar error pero si al momento de ejecutar el aplicativo. 
Antes de ejecutar busca el .dll generado que contenga esas clases en la carpate release y copiales en la debug.

Comment: El archivo .dll ya se genera automáticamente en la carpeta debug en mi caso. Así que no es ese el problema.